# How to skip an Avro serialization exception in KafkaStreams API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka application that is written by KafkaStreams Java api. It reads data from Mysql binlog and do some stuff that is irrelevant to my question. The problem is one particular row produces error in deserialization from avro. I can dig into Avro schema file and find the problem but as a whole what I need is a forgiving exception handler that upon encountering such error does not bring the whole application to halt.
This is the main part of my stream app:

```java
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = watchForCourierUpdate(builder);

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), properties);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));
    }

    private static StreamsBuilder watchForCourierUpdate(StreamsBuilder builder){
        CourierUpdateListener courierUpdateListener = new CourierUpdateListener(builder);
        courierUpdateListener.start();
        return builder;
    }

    private static Properties configProperties(){

        Properties streamProperties = new Properties();

        streamProperties.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, Configs.getConfig("schemaRegistryUrl"));
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "courier_app");
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Configs.getConfig("bootstrapServerUrl"));
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/tmp/state_dir");
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "3");
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.METRICS_RECORDING_LEVEL_CONFIG, "DEBUG");
        streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                CourierSerializationException.class);

        return streamProperties;

    }
```

This is my CourierSerializationException class:

```java
public class CourierSerializationException implements ProductionExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse handle(ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> producerRecord, Exception e) {
        Logger.logError("Failed to de/serialize entity from " + producerRecord.topic() + " topic.\n" + e);
        return ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {

    }
}
```

Still, whenever an avro deserialization exception happens the stream shuts down and the application does not continue. Am I missing something!

Comment: What exactly is the exception you're getting?

Comment: Seems like you need this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-399%3A+Extend+ProductionExceptionHandler+to+cover+serialization+exceptions

Comment: @cricket_007 I cannot remember exactly but something like expected long got union. And thank you, it happens that all my kafka related questions are answered by you :)

Comment: In my experience, that error means your schema is wrong. But you're using generic avro, so it should be fine unless someone broke the schema in the registry

Comment: @cricket_007 yes in fact my schema was wrong and a tiny bit different from what debezium had generated. My problem is why my supposedly forgiving exception handler still halts the application?

Comment: If the schema changed, the registry would reject it before it even was produced into the topic from Debezium. Also, based on what I posted, serialization exceptions are not handled. The exception handler is if your processing nodes throw exceptions

Comment: @cricket_007It was produced based on the schema in schema registry and was put in the topic. I was using a slightly different schema to deserialize it from that topic.
Regarding the second part of your comment so there is no way I can handle serialization exception?

Comment: How are you using a different schema? The GenericAvroSerde cannot do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to do this with the default.deserialization.exception.handler provided by kafka? you can use LogAndContinueExceptionHandler which will log and continue.

I may be wrong but i think creating a Customexception by implementing ProductionExceptionHandler only works for network related error on the kafka side.

add this to the properties and see what happens:

```
> props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
```